# How to standardise query parameters when implementing multiple similar FastAPI endpoints?

Tags: python, fastapi, endpoint

I have a FastAPI application with 90 endpoints and most of them share the same query parameters.

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, Path, Query

router = APIRouter()

def get_session() -> Session:
    SETUP_DB_CONNECTION

@router.get("/ENDPOINT_1")
def endpoint_1(
    db: Session = Depends(get_session),
    id_family: int = Query(default=...),
    tenant: str = Query(default=...),
    id_owner: Optional[int] = Query(default=None),
    from_date: str = Query(default=...),
    to_date: str = Query(default=...),
    interval: Interval = Query(default="month"),
) -> RESPONSE_TYPE_1:
  ENDPOINT_BODY_2

@router.get("/ENDPOINT_2")
def total_value(
    db: Session = Depends(get_session),
    id_family: int = Query(default=...),
    tenant: str = Query(default=...),
    id_owner: Optional[int] = Query(default=None),
    from_date: str = Query(default=...),
    to_date: str = Query(default=...),
    interval: Interval = Query(default="month"),
) -> RESPONSE_TYPE_2:
   ENDPOINT_BODY_2
```

I would like to avoid copying and pasting repeatedly exactly the same set of parameters.
Does anybody have an idea on how could I do that?

I was thinking about writing a callable class like:

```
class StandardProcessor:
    """Processor with standard constructor."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        tenant: Tenant,
        id_family: int,
        id_owner: Optional[int],
        from_date: str,
        to_date: str,
    ):
        """
        Instantiate processor class.

        :param tenant: database schema
        :param id_family: family identifier
        :param id_owner: owner identifier
        :param from_date: start date
        :param to_date: end date
        """
        self.id_family = id_family
        self.tenant = tenant
        self.id_owner: Union[int, str] = "null" if id_owner is None else id_owner
        self.from_date = from_date
        self.to_date = to_date
    
    def process(self, db: Session) -> Any:
        """
        Process data extracted from db session.

        :param db: db session
        :return: processed data
        """
        MY_LOGIC_HERE


class StandardEndpoint(WithLogging):
    """Standard endpoint."""

    def __init__(
            self,
            processor: Type[StandardProcessor]
    ):
        """
        Instantiate standard endpoint.

        :param processor: processor instance
        """
        self.processor = processor

    def __call__(
            self,
            db: Session = Depends(get_session),
            id_family: int = Query(default=...),
            tenant: str = Query(default=...),
            id_owner: Optional[int] = Query(default=None),
            from_date: str = Query(default=...),
            to_date: str = Query(default=...),
    interval: Interval = Query(default="month"),
    ) -> Any:
        """
        Call standard endpoint.

        :return: processed results
        """
        return self.processor(id_family=id_family, id_owner=id_owner, tenant=tenant, from_date=from_date, to_date=to_date).process(db)
```

So that I shift the implementation of the body of my endpoints to the StandardProcessorClass (a thing that I am already doing for other purposes) and the actual endpoint could be defined as as:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, Path, Query

router = APIRouter()

router.get("/ENDPOINT_1")(StandardEndpoint(StandardProcessor)())
```

But this does not work since it doesn't seem to resolve correctly input parameters returning `AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'query'` which makes me think that it does not handle correctly at least the Depends input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation provides a [shortcut using classes](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#shortcut). In your case, you would define a class (I'm using a Pydantic model) for the shared parameters, and then just use that instead of the parameter list:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Params(BaseModel):
    id_family: int
    tenant: str
    id_owner: Optional[int] = None
    from_date: str
    to_date: str
    interval: Interval = "month"


@router.get("/ENDPOINT_1")
def endpoint_1(
    db: Session = Depends(get_session), params: Params = Depends()
) -> RESPONSE_TYPE_1:
  ENDPOINT_BODY_2


@router.get("/ENDPOINT_2")
def total_value(
    db: Session = Depends(get_session), params: Params = Depends()
) -> RESPONSE_TYPE_2:
   ENDPOINT_BODY_2
```

Comment: It's important to note that while you can use a class or a function exists, it uses _regular classes_ or a function, and not Pydantic models. A Pydantic model would make the endpoint assume that the data comes as a JSON body, I think? Did you verify the behavior of your example?

Comment: Thanks! You're right, it can be any class (I've updated the answer). It of course the class can still be a pydantic model, as long as you use `= Depends()` (the example above works).